# Google Apps Scripts: Remove data when dates < today + xx days

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a Google Sheet with 5 columns and dates of the last check. I want to only keep the entries when the number of days since the last check is > 10 days.

The Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nD7CXraydrAwOh7q7QFDLveVW76wRNU0ago4h-ORn8U/edit?usp=sharing

```html
function check(){

/** Variables **/ 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); var sh1 = ss.getSheetByName('Data Processing');

/** Remove duplicates **/ 
  var sh1data = sh1.getDataRange().getValues(); 
  var sh1newData = []; 
  for (var i in sh1data) { 
    var row = sh1data[i]; 
    var duplicate = false; 
    for (var j in sh1newData) {
/* DATE */
      var today=new Date().valueOf(); 
      var sec=1000;  var min=60*sec;  var hour=60*min;  var day=24*hour; // Do the conversions  
      var sh1DateChecked = sh1newData[j][4].valueOf(); 
      var diff=today-sh1DateChecked; 
      var days=Math.floor(diff/day); // Number of Days since the last check
      
if(row[0] == sh1newData[j][0] && row[1] == sh1newData[j][1] && days < 10)
{ duplicate = true; } } 
    if (!duplicate) { sh1newData.push(row);
                     
} 
  } 
  sh1.clearContents();
  sh1.getRange(1, 1, sh1newData.length, sh1newData[0].length).setValues(sh1newData); 

}
```

Comment: Can I ask you about the detail of current issue of your script?

Comment: The script does nothing when  && days < 10 is there. If I remove  && days < 10 it does what it's supposed to do: remove the duplicates.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, from your replying, I couldn't still understand about your situation and goal. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution ignores the code's mention of "duplicates" and focuses on your stated question of removing dates less than 10 days old.  However, if you need to remove duplicates as well, it can be easily added.

I propose you put your condition in a function that takes a row of data as input and returns a boolean (true/false) such as

```js
function dateCheckedOlderThan10Days(row) {
  return getDays(row[4]) > 10;
}

function getDays(date) {
  const sec = 1000;
  const min = 60 * sec;
  const hour = 60 * min;
  const day = 24 * hour;  
  return Math.floor((new Date() - date)/day);  
}
```

*(Note how you can completely extract the `getDays` function from your main function.  That reduces the amount of code you have to think about inside each function definition.)*

This function will fit perfectly into `Array.prototype.filter`, and the naming of the function makes it very clear what you expect to happen.

```
const dataOlderThan10Days = ss.getSheetByName('Data Processing')
  .getDataRange()
  .getValues()
  .filter(dateCheckedOlderThan10Days);
```

Here is the `checked` function refactored into several functions:

#### Code.js

```js
function check() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Data Processing');
  const data = dataSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  const dataOlderThan10Days = data
    .slice(1) // removes header row; comment out if you don't have a header row
    .filter(dateCheckedOlderThan10Days);
  dataSheet.clearContents();
  //dataOlderThan10Days.unshift(data[0]); // <-- if you want to restore the headers
  setData(dataSheet, dataOlderThan10Days);
}

function dateCheckedOlderThan10Days(row) {
  return getDays(row[HEADINGS.DATE_CHECKED]) > 10;
}

const HEADINGS = {
  FIRST_NAME: 0,
  LAST_NAME: 1,
  SALARY: 2,
  AGE: 3,
  DATE_CHECKED: 4
};

function setData(sheet, data) {
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
}

function getDays(date) {
  const sec = 1000;
  const min = 60 * sec;
  const hour = 60 * min;
  const day = 24 * hour;  
  return Math.floor((new Date() - date)/day);  
}
```